# Proper activeweb configuration for pages with foreign language characters

Tags: activeweb

I have just created new web application based on **activeweb** framework and by default it shows me "?" for all foreign language characters. Something like this:

> ? ????????? ??????
>   ???? ????????? ?? 
>   ?????? ??????????
>
> ? ??? ???? ??????????
>   ??????????? ????????

English characters are displayed ok.

Here is my **web.xml** config:

> ```
> <display-name>activeweb</display-name>
>
> <session-config>
>     <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
> </session-config>
>
>
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>dispatcher</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher</filter-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>exclusions</param-name>
>         <param-value>css,img,fonts,images,js,html,GwtExample,ico</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>root_controller</param-name>
>         <param-value>home</param-value>
>     </init-param>
> </filter>
>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>dispatcher</filter-name>
>     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
>
> <welcome-file-list>
>     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
> </welcome-file-list>
> ```

I expect that this problem might be related to encoding in **activeweb** internals or I have to apply special setting. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: By foreign, do you mean non-english/latin characters?

Comment: Yes, non-English characters, for example Russian letters like in the word "Привет"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because ActiveWeb does nothing about encoding by default, and what you get comes from the servlet container.In order to force a specific encoding (UTF-8, I assume), you need to add a line of configuration to the web.xml file:

`<filter>
        <filter-name>dispatcher</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>exclusions</param-name>
            <param-value>css,images,js,ico</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>root_controller</param-name>
            <param-value>home</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>`

This will force UTF-8 encoding on request as well as response.